# Custom attribute only on specific classes

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, attributes, postsharp

I would like to define a constrait on my custom (PostSharp) attribute. My goal is to get error or warning while compile time, if class *X* dont implements *Y* interface but it has my attribute.

So this should work:

```
[MyAttributeOnlyForY]
public class X : Y { ... }
```

but this should break the compile process:

```
[MyAttributeOnlyForY]
public class X { ... }
```

How is it possible?

**The reason**

This attribute works like an aspect (this is PostSharp [attribute](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp.HxS/UserGuide/Laos/AspectKinds/OnExceptionAspect.html)), and I want to be sure that the weaved class provides all needed information for this attribute.

I want to avoid *null* result on

```
(eventArgs.Instance as ILoggerServiceOwner)
```

and I think complie time checking is a good practice.

**Solution**

I've found a perfect start here: [Validating attribute usage with PostSharp Aspects](http://karlagius.com/2008/01/29/validating-attribute-usage-with-postsharp-aspects/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the PostSharp method CompileTimeValidate and use reflection to check if type has a derived type. However, it may be computationally expensive do look for all types in the assembly.

Comment: and some ideas from here: http://www.postsharp.org/forum/postsharp-laos/onmethodboundaryaspect-compiletimevalidate-param-issues-t333.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible.
A better solution might be to use the Obsolete attribute on your custom attribute constructor to warn that the target class should implement the interface Y.